Congruency of two matrices over the field of rational numbers.
Consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}$ over the field $\Bbb Q$ of rationals.Which of the following matrices are congruent to $A$ over  $\Bbb Q$?

$(1).$ $A_1=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\
0&-2
\end{bmatrix}$$(2).$ $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}$$(3).$ $A_3=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}$$(4).$ $A_4=\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\
4&5
\end{bmatrix}$


We know that, Two matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $n\times n$  are congruent over any field $\mathbb{F}$ if there exists $P\in GL(n,\mathbb{F})$ s.t. $A=P^{t}BP$.
Now,$A=P^{t}BP\implies \frac{det(A)}{det(B)}={(det(P))}^2$.Since,  $det(P)\in\mathbb{F}\implies\pm\sqrt{\frac{det(A)}{det(B)}}\in\mathbb{F}$.Hence in view of the above discussion $A_2$ is not congruent to $A$(as $\pm\sqrt{\frac{det(A)}{det(A_1)}}\notin\mathbb{Q}$).Now for other options how should i proceeed?

Is there any necessary and sufficient condition for congruency of two matrices over field of rationals(Like Sylvester's criteria in case of reals)?If two matrices are congruent over $\mathbb{Q}$ then are their invariants(rank,signature,index) same?


If they are congruent over $\mathbb Q$, they are congruent over $\mathbb R$, so Sylvester should be a clue.

@RobertIsrael It means if they are not congruent over $\Bbb R$ then they are not congruent over $\Bbb Q$ and If rhey are congruent over $\Bbb Q$ then they have same invariants.

@RobertIsrael This is one way.

@RobertIsrael What if they are congruent over $\Bbb R$?Then can we say anything over $Q$?

see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

please define signature and index

@WillJagy thank you .

@user8675309 Index of a real symmetric matrix is defined as the number of positive eigenvalues and signature of a real symmetric matrix is defined as the number of positive eigen values minus number of negative eigenvalues.

You need to define index, signature, etc. over $\mathbb Q$ which is the field you are asking about.  E.g. $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ has no rational eigenvalues.

@user8675309 how can I do this?

my suggested definition for signature would be to add up the number of positive entries and subtract the number of negative entries of a diagonal matrix that $A$ is congruent to.   You know this number is the same for any diagonal matrix since $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb R$ so Sylvester's Law of Inertia holds.

@user8675309 So,A and B are congruent over Q iff they have same invariants(rank,signature and index).

You need to more carefully think this through.  I gave you a definition suggestion for signature and I pointed out that it does not depend on diagonal matrix congruence choice.  That is all.  Also I think your signature definition over reals is non-standard -- the standard one is a tuple $(m, r)$

@user8675309 I will work on your advice.Thank you.

$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{3}{2} &    \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\frac{1}{2} &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{3}{2} &    \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\frac{1}{2} &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{3}{4} &    \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\frac{1}{4} &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{3}{4} &    \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\frac{1}{2} &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & 4 \\ 
4 & 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{7}{12} &    \frac{ 1 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\frac{1}{12} &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & 0 \\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{3} \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{7}{12} &    \frac{ 1 }{ 12 }  \\ 
\frac{1}{4} &  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{n+1}{2n} &    \frac{ n-1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\frac{n-1}{2n} &  \frac{ n+1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
n & 0 \\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{n} \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
\frac{n+1}{2n} &    \frac{ n-1 }{ 2n }  \\ 
\frac{n-1}{2} &  \frac{ n+1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
Note: I was thinking of $n$ as an integer, but this matrix product works fine for any rational nonzero $n.$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
